# Using "<g:message tag in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, grails, internationalization, gsp

I want to use below tag in javascript to read resourcebundle value.

```
var myText = "<g:message code='${steps[i].text}' />" ;
```

steps[i].text is not static and keeps on changing that's why I need to pass value of "steps[i].text" to the resourcebundle.

If I use,

```
var myText = "<g:message code='a.b.key' />" ;
```

then it works fine.
But for below line it gives error as below:

```
var myText = "<g:message code='${steps[i].text}' />" ;

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: Error executing tag <r:script>: Error evaluating expression [steps[i].text] on line [393]: Cannot get property 'null' on null object
```

My code is in .gsp file which is capable of reading resource bundle.

Comment: Is `steps[i].text` something in your model on the server side or something client side? The message tag is server-side and won't work with client-side values for the code parameter.

Comment: yes steps[i].text is coming from server side but at client side I'm getting that correctly. because If i don't do localization then I can see that value correctly on my page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you are rendering the gsp grails transform the g:message in the corresponding message, but it is not transforming the ${steps[i].text} in the corresponding label.

Maybe you can solve the problem using the args of the message tag:

> .gsp

```
<g:message code='a.b.key' args="[i]" />
```

> .messages.properties

```
a.b.key = whatever {0} means
```

Comment: steps[i].text is totally unknown value . That can be read at runtime only. steps[i].text is coming from backend. I can do alert(steps[i].text) and value is getting correctly. That's why I can't use <g:message code='a.b.key' args="[i]" />

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might work for you:

```
var myText = "${g.message(code:steps[i].text)}";
```

I'm assuming here that 'steps' is a server-side variable and not a javascript one.